# Fill in missing enumeration values in table (R)

Tags: r, enumeration

I would like to  fill in the missing values in one column in a table. In the column `combName` the values should go up to `20-400` and continue with `21-1` to `21-400` and so on. For every missing value a new row should be created with the value in the right enumerated order and 0 in all other fields of the row.

```
   combName sumLength RootID
   <chr>        <dbl>  <int>
 1 20-1          8.05      1
 2 20-2          4.61      1
 3 20-3         14.5       1
 4 20-8          2.29      1
 5 20-10        14.7       1
 6 20-11        23.0       4
 7 20-12        17.0       5
 8 20-13        66.9      14
 9 20-14        39.1       9
10 20-15        12.5       6
# ... with 1,099 more rows
```

Are there any ideas how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of functions from `tidyr` library.

Divide `combName` into two columns splitting on `'-'`. For every value in `col1` create rows from 1 to 400 in `col2` and finally combine `col1` and `col2` into one column again.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(combName, c('col1', 'col2'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE) %>%
  complete(col1, col2 = 1:400, fill = list(sumLength = 0, RootID = 0)) %>%
  unite(combName, col1, col2, sep = '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

We use `expand.grid` from `base R` to create a full combination dataset

```
full_dat <- data.frame(combName = do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(Var1 = 
  sub("-.*", "", unique(df$combName)), Var2 = 1:400), sep="-"))
```

and `merge` with the original dataset

```
out <- merge(full_data, df, by = "combName", all.x = TRUE)
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
```